# Rails create in model - except attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an `:expense` from a `:recurringexpense`

The `:recurring expense` has attributes that are not in `:expense`.

I thought this would work:

```
def copy_to_expense
  @recurringexpense = Recurringexpense.find(params[:id]) # find original recurring expense
  @expense = Expense.create(@recurringexpense.attributes).except(:frequency, :last_date)

  redirect_to @recurringexpenses, notice: 'Expense was successfully created.'
end
```

But, I'm getting this:

```
unknown attribute: frequency
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `except` directly on the attributes hash:

```
@expense = Expense.create(@recurringexpense.attributes.except(:frequency, :last_date))
```

As you note in your comment, you also need to make sure your keys in the `except` argument are the right type. You could also do this with

```
.attributes.symbolize_keys.except(...)
```

Comment: This worked `    @expense = Expense.create(@recurringexpense.attributes.except("frequency", "last_date"))`

Comment: Cool, or you could precede `except` with a call to `symbolize_keys`.